# Spring Tool Suite 3.9.6 Editor refreshing repeatedly

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, spring-tool-suite

I installed STS 3.9.6 in ubuntu 18.04 and the editor is refreshing frequently, so it is very difficult to work in this way.

Thanks for all

Comment: *Which* editor?

Comment: For example I have a xml file (pom.xml) or java file so I can not codifying because it is refreshing

Comment: Do you mean repainting?

Comment: That sounds like [Eclipse bug 517671](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=517671). Which GTK version do you use and does upgrading GTK fix your issue?

Comment: you are right, there the bug is commented and I found the solution, set the input method  in "~/.profile"   "export GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus"

Comment: Great. I've added it as an answer in case someone else runs into the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like the problem that has been reported as [**Eclipse bug 517671**](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=517671) and is caused by a **bug in GTK3** which seems to be fixed in GTK 3.22.11 and higher.

The following solutions/workarounds can be found in the comments of the mentioned bug:

- **Upgrade GTK3 to 3.22.11 or higher**, e. g. by upgrading Ubuntu (see [comment #7](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=517671#c7))
- In **`~/.profile`** add **`export GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus`** (see [comment #58](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=517671#c58); already verified by you)
- Only if both of the above are not possible or do not work, do `export SWT_GTK3=0` before running Eclipse (see [comment #1](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=517671#c1))